# What DTD should I use in JSF 1.2/2.0/2.1 to validate my configuration XML?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, dtd

currently, I have following DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">
```

And it does not validate the 1.2 tags, like:

```
managed-bean => managed-property
```

And I cannot find a newer version form sun:
http://java.sun.com/dtd/

from some tutorials, I see people simply not using DTD for JSF 2 at all, should I try to find a DTD or is DTD deprecated for JSF 1.2+?

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSF 2.0 doesn't have a DTD. It's a XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"
>
    <!-- Config here -->
</faces-config>
```

The same story applies to JSF 1.2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2"
>
    <!-- Config here -->
</faces-config>
```

If you were using a JSF 1.1 DTD on JSF 1.2/2.0, then those applications will run in JSF 1.1 mode. You really don't want to have that.

Comment: Just replace 2_0 and 2.0 by 1_2 and 1.2. I added it to the answer.

Comment: thank you, will mark it as answered after the cooling down 7 minutes.